# MySQL using JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, inner-join, group-concat

Struggling to get this query working:

```
$query_search = "SELECT questionnaires_index.id, questionnaires_index.ea_num, questionnaires_index.address, questionnaires_index.status, questionnaires_index.json_stored users.username FROM questionnaires_index INNER JOIN users ON questionnaires_index.interviewer_id = users.id WHERE questionnaires_index.interviewer_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM users WHERE supervisor = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'))";
```

Getting this error:

> Error in query: . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '.username FROM questionnaires_index INNER JOIN
>   users ON users.id = questionnaire' at line 1

The query was working until I added the users.username to the result set with the JOIN statement. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a comma

$query_search = "SELECT questionnaires_index.id, questionnaires_index.ea_num, questionnaires_index.address, questionnaires_index.status, questionnaires_index.json_stored, users.username FROM questionnaires_index INNER JOIN users ON questionnaires_index.interviewer_id = users.id WHERE questionnaires_index.interviewer_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM users WHERE supervisor = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'))";

Comment: Oh my. That's what happens after hours of struggling to get this query working.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to forgot to put a comma between questionnaires_index.json_stored and users.username.

```
$query_search = "SELECT questionnaires_index.id, questionnaires_index.ea_num, questionnaires_index.address, questionnaires_index.status, questionnaires_index.json_stored ,users.username FROM questionnaires_index INNER JOIN users ON questionnaires_index.interviewer_id = users.id WHERE questionnaires_index.interviewer_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM users WHERE supervisor = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'))
```